# Bot Framework Composer DirectLine

Tags: azure, bots, whatsapp, bot-framework-composer

I hope you can help me in this problem
I have created a chatbot in the azure framework
Bot Framework Composer and I want to use it in WhatsApp Bussines
. My problem comes for the reason that bot framework composer
It still does not have a direct channel to whatsapp or any
platform like Twilio or Gupshup. I was recommended to use
the azure "DirectLine" channel that comes integrated, to take
the endpoint of my chatbot produced by azure when deploying it
in my group of resources and so with the keys of the channel that I
provides "DirecLine" to be able to interact with my chatbot. try
do the tests with the endpoint of my chatbot through Postman
but I have not been successful, despite following the documentation as indicated
microsoft, gives me an answer that is not authorized

I folow this steps
[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH8l1.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYOUK.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuMLT.png)

[step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4OIZ.png)

Comment: Please share more details. Is this problem really related to [tag:composer-php]?

Comment: oh, no, sorry, is a problem of azure bot framewor composer

Answer (score 0):

This is regarding the authentication error. To rectify the problem, here is the road map to follow.

1. Goto [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com/)
2. Search for **Azure bot**

[image]

Give the details of bot handle name and subscription. Mention the valid resource group name.
3.  After creating the bot. Click on **Channels** where we need to create **Direct Line** access

[image]

4. Select the **Direct Line**

[image]

5. Click on **New Site**

[image]

6. Create a new site and key the key information

[image]

Now, using those keys we need to perform authentication operation.

Under the version in the above image, need to select 3.0, as Azure Direct Line authentication is functioning with REST API with 3.0 version of Direct line API

[image]

To enhance the authentication option, you can enable the **Enhanced Authentication Option** which is not functioning according to the current requirement in the case mentioned in question.